# How do I multiply a dataframe column by a float constant?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a column by a float. I have the code for it here:

```
if str(cMachineName)==str("K42"):
        df_temp.loc[:, "P"] *= float((105.0* 59.0*math.pi*0.95/1000)/3540)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: What is `df_temp['P'].dtype` ? Is it numeric?

Comment: Please show a complete, self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `type(df_temp["P"]) gives pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: `df_temp['P'].dtype gives dtype('O')`

Comment: Please make an effort to have more legible titles. Omit spelling mistakes, because your question will remain on the site for years, so you don't want it looking as shabby as it is.

Comment: You have asked many questions in this tag already, please get the spelling right... it's not "phyton" or "pyhton".... or "phtyon"

Comment: My mistake. Apologies. I will remember it from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is some non numeric values like `45` as string:

Solution is converting to `float`, `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'P':[1,2.5,'45']})

print (df_temp['P'].dtype)
object

df_temp["P"] = df_temp["P"].astype(float)
df_temp["P"] *= float((105.0* 59.0*math.pi*0.95/1000)/3540)
print (df_temp)
          P
0  0.005223
1  0.013057
2  0.235030
```

Another problem is non numeric data like `gh`, for converting is necessary [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stble/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for converting them to `NaN`s:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'P':[1,2.5,'gh']})

print (df_temp['P'].dtype)
object

df_temp["P"] = pd.to_numeric(df_temp["P"], errors='coerce')
print (df_temp)
     P
0  1.0
1  2.5
2  NaN

df_temp["P"] *= float((105.0* 59.0*math.pi*0.95/1000)/3540)
print (df_temp)

          P
0  0.005223
1  0.013057
2       NaN
```

Comment: I have checked my column for strings, it does not have any such string value.

Comment: 'df_temp['P'].dtype gives me dtype('O')`

Comment: Yes, `O` means object.

Comment: @jezrael -- explicit float(..) in second line is not needed perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simple an answer, but this worked for me and is relatively simple.

```
Dataframe["new column"]  = (dataframe ["old column"] * by float constant)
January1st["weight_lb"] = (January1st["weight_kg"] * 2.2)
```

`Dataframe.head()` to see whether it worked.